# Horizontal Table With DataList And DIVs?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, .net-2.0, datalist

I'm trying to create a table layout with headers on the left and horizontally aligned fields. (See mock-up below.) I'm trying to accomplish this using a DataList -- stuck with .NET 2.0 -- and wrapped in a div with a scrollbar on the x-axis so that if enough groups are visible, a scroll bar will appear.

```
               Group One      Group Two      Group Three
Header One      Value          Value          Value
Header Two      Value          Value          Value
Header Three    Value          Value          Value
```

I'm struggling with two points, both seen in the below code and jsFiddle.

- How do I keep the #itm blocks in a single line without explicitly defining a width on the #wrapper?

  - **white-space: nowrap on #wrapper works here.**
- How do I keep a consistent height on rows, even if data should vertically expand its parent DIV?

  - **Setting an explicit height will work for me, given an approximate field length.**

**Original jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6yXV/1/**

**Updated with fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/D6yXV/7/**

HTML:

```
<div id="hdr">
    <label>Header One</label>
    <label>Header Two</label>
    <label class="highlight">Header Three</label>
    <label>Header Four</label>
</div>

<div id="itm">
    <span>Some Data</span>
    <span>More Data</span>
    <span class="highlight">Even More Data</span>
    <span>No More Data</span>
</div>

<div id="itm">
    <span>Some Data</span>
    <span>More Data</span>
    <span class="highlight">Actually, this is a large field and could stretch the row out some.</span>
    <span>Even More Data</span>
</div>

<div id="itm">
    <span>Some Data</span>
    <span>More Data</span>
    <span class="highlight">Even More Data</span>
    <span>No More Data</span>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { overflow-x: auto; }
#hdr, #itm { display: inline-block; padding: 3px; width: 150px; }
#itm { border-left: solid 1px #000; }
#hdr label { font-weight: 700; display: block; }
#itm span { display: block; }
.highlight { background-color: #EEE; }
```

Comment: Why not use a table for this, as this is the exact thing tables are good for?

Comment: I guess I could wrap the DataList in a table and create td tags inside the header and item templates.

Comment: Per Dustin, that would be the sensible approach for what is basically "tabular" data :)

Comment: If you do not need the added features of the `datalist` then I suggest using a repeater. A little cleaner in the end, IMO.

Comment: Thinking about this more, if I were to use a table, how would I create that layout with a databound control? I would think you'd need to have each dataitem be a table row, which keeps me from the "dataitem as column" layout.

Comment: Or use a ListView which gives really clean HTML... use its templates for your table

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck using the .NET 2.0 Framework. ListView was introduced in 3.5. Unless there's a way to use that control in 2.0, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Then follow Dustin's advice re: Repeater...

Comment: How would I organize that in a Repeater ItemTemplate then? Each DataItem would correspond to a table row, which would give me a standard table with headers on top.

Comment: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Answer (score 0):

Put a "float:left;" on the items? And remove itm from the hdr rule :)

Better yet, use a table (or Repeater) for tabular data :)

Comment: Float was the first thing I tried. I get the same result. Why do you suggest removing itm from the hdr rule? I had intended the two to share properties. Bad practice? Personal preference?

Comment: Here, the hdr should be in its own separate div (on top with a "clear" between it and the itm "rows"). If the floats are wrapping on you it's because they are too wide... the first few should still be working (side-by-side)

Comment: Right. The floats should wrap if they're too wide. What I want though, is to wrap everything in an element with a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Scroll bar is bad mojo...try and fit the four "columns" in a 960-wide layout (presuming desktop browser here and not mobile)

Comment: By default, we're going to show three columns, which I can account for. But the client wants to display more than that if chosen.

Comment: Then leave space for that and use a panel with "Visible" set to false... easier than programmatically setting a CSS "display:none;" rule...

Answer (score 0):

Seriously why aren't you using <table>'s?

Comment: That would solve my problems but now I need to figure how I would organize each DataItem as a column into the ItemTemplate of the control.