# Group data in columns (instead of rows) in an HTML table using data bound control?

Tags: asp.net, html, .net-2.0, databound-controls

Is there a way to group data into columns using a data bound control in ASP.NET?

Normally, binding a control to an array of objects, I think of each object as a row. In a typical HTML table, the markup flows the same way and you get get something like this;

```
            HEADER1     HEADER2     HEADER3
Object1     Field1      Field2      Field3
Object2     Field1      Field2      Field3
Object3     Field1      Field2      Field3
```

What I want is this;

```
            Object1     Object2     Object3     
HEADER1     Field1      Field1      Field1
HEADER2     Field2      Field2      Field2
HEADER3     Field3      Field3      Field3
```

Outside of modifying the data so that each data item of the bound control holds all of Field1, then Field2, Field3, (instead of Object1, Object2, Object3,) I can't think of a way to do this.

Note, I am using .NET 2.0 and am stuck with those controls.

This is an extension of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706389/horizontal-table-with-datalist-and-divs) where I wanted to float DIVs with each DIV reflecting an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rotating the control, how about rotating the data?
I found this clever article on CodeProject that has a method to flip a DataSet on its axis: [Vertical Rows in Datagrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Vertical_rows_in_Datagrid.aspx)

Here's a quick way to transpose an array:

```
public static void transpose(int[][] a, int[][] b, int width, int height){ 
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
      b[j][i] = a[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That would work if I were binding to a DataSet, but I'm binding to an array of objects.

Comment: i added method to transpose array

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm working with a one-dimensional array of complex objects with any number of properties to pull data from.

Comment: While not rotating the data per se, I ended up grouping data together in a manner that allowed me to load it without issue.